# Area growth of minimal submanifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, minimal-surfaces

Let $(M, g)$ be a $(n+1)$-dimensional Riemannian manifold and let $\Sigma^n \subset M$ be a properly embedded orientable minimal submanifold.

I am interested in the volume growth of $\Sigma$. I know that in the Euclidean case one can show that $\Sigma$ has polynomial growth if it is graphical (it follows from a calibration argument). Can one get a similar result under weaker assumptions, like just assuming $\Sigma$ to be stable?

Comment: Volume growth is related with curvature  (cf. Bishop-Gunther theorem)